# Does A Recovery Floppy Disk Wipe Current Hard Drive?

Tags: recovery-disk

So I have a computer from years ago, which had windows 98 running on it. When I went to boot it up today, it said it needed a boot disk. I have a Windows 98 rescue disk (floppy disk), but if I was to run it, would it wipe the current hard drive data? Thanks

Comment: Unless you have something to recover from it don't bother. "From years ago" is an understatement. You may try some light Linux distro but that's it. No currently supported Windows will run on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends on exactly what sort of recovery disk you have...

Standard Windows 95/98 boot disks do nothing more than start MS-DOS from the floppy – they're like "live CDs" but for DOS. (IIRC, in Win98 they even have a few recovery tools in a ramdisk, like a modern live CD would.)

On the other hand, custom-made boot or recovery disks can do just about anything. They *can* be made to reinstall the OS without asking. They *can* be made to reformat the entire system disk, or even all disks.

(For example, if the disk has "Darik's Boot and Nuke" written on it, do not use it.)